# App targeting only Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an app using Visual Studio Express 2013. I selected a blank application(Universal) template and there is no blank template available specific to phone.

Doing so has created an app with 2 c# classes targeting to both phone and desktop.

How can I create an app which I want to target only for windows phone. Will deleting one of the class from the project solve the purpose?

Answer (score 2):

I think You should select **windows phone Apps** Template if you are going for only windows phone app.

[image: Image for selection of new Template]

Comment: to do that you should download Phone SDK. I think his reason to not see `Windows Phone Apps` might be that, am I right?

Comment: if he is having Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows that also includes tools for Windows Phone 8.0 development, so no need to donwload sdk.

Comment: well, yes. I didn't catch that.

Answer (score -1):

If you're targeting only `WindowsPhone`, then you should be going with the `Silverlight` app for WP or the normal `WinRT` apps for WP.

`Universal` app is where it targets both the WP and the `Store` apps.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is wrong. Windows Phone 8.1 apps do not have to be Silverlight apps. and Windows Phone will not be running on Silverlight in the future, as Silverlight has been retired.

Comment: @dBlisse I never told that it's a must to go with the Silverlight, it's just an option if you've read it properly. Can you please justify that WP will not run in Silverlight towards future?